# Would this pattern call memory leak

Tags: java

If there is a singleton instance of SomeClass and some other class repeatedly call createMap() method on instance of SomeClass then would there ever be a memory leak? I tested this with a 50000 loop and monitored heap and I dont see the leak but would like opinion.

```
class SomeClass {
    Map<String, String> someMap;

    public void createMap() {
        someMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        System.out.println("Created map");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You'll be creating tons of HashMap instances which will be GCed (eventually)

Comment: What makes you think this will cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - NO.

Long answer - depends on complete code under `try` and how `createMap()` is called.

I am assuming from your question that you are concerned about functionality of your app and overall performance. Memory is just one aspect to it. Your Singlton class would break right away from logic perspective as you do not have concurrency control on `createMap()` and multiple parallel call may overwrite `someMap`.

It also depends what you do under `try{` block. If you are sending `someMap` outside to another method or so, there may be a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

This would not create a memory leak.

You have one variable that is a reference to a `HashMap` and can only reference one `HashMap`.

In a loop, the previous hashmap would lose its reference and then become a candidate for garbage collection.